# Changing a Custom Labels Master language

Tags: customlabel, translation

Some time ago I accidentally created a custom label in German, while our main org language is English.

I want to update the language of the custom label to English, but this field is not editable if you click on edit in the UI:
[image: edit language screenshot]

I also tried updating this field through the metadata API, but this was not successful either.

I can always delete it and recreate it again in English, but I want to avoid this as the custom label is referenced in multiple places in our code base and I have to update a couple of labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think you're going to need to delete and then recreate it. You've already tried the methods that one would expected to be able to use to change it; particularly the metadata api.